# How to obtain the name of the parent nodes in rpart?

Tags: r, plot, cran, party

Hi I'm currently trying to extract some of the parents node information stored in party object, like ID. For now i can get the IDs for terminal nodes using:

```
 fit<-rpart(CommuteDistance ~.,data = Clients)
 pr<-as.party(fit)
 nodeids(pr,terminal=TRUE)
```

But how I can get the parent IDs? And if is posible how I can get the names of the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Since the node IDs follow a nice pattern, you can determine the parent id simply by parent_id = floor(node_id/2).

Here is a minimal working example to arrive at a table with a mapping of node ids to their parent IDs. In it, I use the rownames_to_column function from the tidyverse to get the node_ids rather than using partykit, but the approach would be similar:

```
library("rpart")
library("tidyverse")
fit <- rpart(Petal.Length ~ ., data = iris)


get_frame_with_parent <- function(x) {
  frame_with_parent <- 
    x$frame %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "node_id") %>%
    mutate(node_id = as.numeric(node_id),
           parent_id = floor(node_id/2))
  frame_with_parent
}
frame_with_parent
```

Getting the node names can be accomplished using labels(fit)

For a minimal working example combining these two things to arrive at a table containing node IDs, node labels, parent IDs and parent labels:

```
library("rpart")
library("tidyverse")
fit <- rpart(Petal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

get_frame_with_parent <- function(x) {
  frame_with_parent <- 
    x$frame %>%
    mutate(node_label = labels(x)) %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "node_id") %>%
    mutate(node_id = as.numeric(node_id),
           parent_id = floor(node_id/2))
  
  frame_with_parent <-
    frame_with_parent %>%
    left_join(
      dplyr::select(frame_with_parent, node_id, node_label),
      by = c("parent_id" = "node_id"),
      suffix = c("", ".y")
    ) %>%
    dplyr::rename(parent_label = node_label.y)
  
  frame_with_parent
}
get_frame_with_parent(fit)
```

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but I came across this via a google search and with no accepted answer, I figured this might be able to help someone else out down the road.

Comment: Would it be possible to obtain the ids in a way that nodes are indexed according to the pruning process? That is, the highest id would correspond to the first branch that would be collaplsed according to the `cp` table, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no readily available function to extract this conveniently. But it is not hard to simply traverse the recursive `partynode` structure and get the custom quantities you are interested in. It also helps to convert the recursive `partynode` to a flat list first.

For a reproducible example, consider the following `rpart` tree and its `party` representation:

```
library("rpart")
fit <- rpart(Petal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
library("partykit")
pr <- as.party(fit)
```

Afterwards you can easily convert to `as.list(pr$node)` which returns all the information from the recursive `partynode` structure. In particular this contains the `$id` of each node and the `$kids` IDs (if any). Thus we can easily extract these with `sapply()` and a custom function:

```
sapply(as.list(pr$node), function(n) {
  if(is.null(n$kids)) c(n$id, NA, NA) else c(n$id, n$kids)
})
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
## [2,]    2   NA    4    5   NA   NA    8   NA   NA
## [3,]    3   NA    7    6   NA   NA    9   NA   NA
```

This shows in the first column that Node 1 has two kids, Nodes 2 and 3. Node 2 is a terminal node because it does not have kids (second column) while Node 3 has two kids again, Nodes 4 and 7 etc.